# OWL-API Intersection of more concepts

Tags: owl-api

I'm new at OWL-API.
I need to represent an intersection of N concepts
So, intersectionOf (C1, C2, ..... CN).
IntersectionOf has two arguments, but how can I do the general purpose solution?
Is it good enough to build an HashSet and then put it into the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

OWLDataFactory has methods for obtaining an intersection that accept collections - usually sets- of class expressions. I believe that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Ignazio said, but with code:

Java Code:

    `OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    Set<OWLClassExpression> mySet = new HashSet<OWLClassExpression>();
    factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(mySet);`

HTH